# Is possible to set TextView to have different widths per line?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

This is what I get so far, using `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_toLeftOf` and `android:layout_toRightOf`

```
[BUTTON1][TEXTVIEW: HERE GOES A TEXT........][BUTTON2]
         [...THAT MUST CONTINUE IN THIS LINE]
```

This is what I need:

```
[BUTTON1][TEXTVIEW: HERE GOES A TEXT........][BUTTON2]
[..........THAT MUST CONTINUE IN THIS LINE...........]
```

I know I can do it with multiples textviews, but I don't know how to split the text to fit exactly first and second lines.

So, is possible to set textview to stay "right of" button1 and "left of" button2, but only in "line1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with `TextView` that platform provides. You may however write own widget to do layout that way. Peek the source of this widget as starting point http://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not-  in android a View is always rectangular.  You can't have a view becoming skinny at the top.